# Join Hive Yarn aplication_id and Ranger Log Audit

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, apache-ranger

On Hadoop Yarn, how can I relate the ***yarn logs -applicationId*** of a transaction with the Hive apache  ranger audit log?

Comment: Did you enable the Hive Ranger plugin?

Comment: I have a couple of months using hadoop, I'm not sure if that pluggin is there. I watch the sessions through Ambari -> Yarn -> Resource Manager UI.

With that I get the application_id which in turn gives me the query.

From the server and with some table of that query doing hdfs dfs -cat / ranger / audit / hiveServer2 / 20200129 / * | grep -i "query"

I get the user. The fact is that if there are several queries doing the same thing, I have no way of determining exactly which is the user corresponding to the original application_id and I can't find how to link it.

Comment: Ambari should have a link to the Ranger UI, where you can search as well